# Como criar um Cascading DropDown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Gostaria de criar um DropDown dependente de outro DropDown em C#, ASP.net - MVC 5, no caso seria um dropDown com os nomes de todos os cliente e em seguida outro DropDown com os telefones do Cliente selecionado no primeiro DropDown. Como fazer?

Classe : Pedido

```
 public class Pedido
{
    public Pedido()
    {
        this.Produtos = new List<Produto>();
    }      

    [Key]
    public int PedidoID { get; set; }

    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome do Cliente")]
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string ClienteFone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]  
    public string   ClienteCidade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string ClienteEstado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string ClienteEndereço { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status to pedido")]
    public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }

    public int EstatusID { get; set; }

    [Display (Name="Data do pedido")]
    public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }

}
```

Create.cshtml

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClienteID, "ClienteID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClienteID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClienteFone, "ClienteFone", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClienteFone", String.Empty)
           @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClienteFone)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteFone)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma, abaixo é um exemplo com uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura

```
clientes(ClienteID, Nome, Telefone)
```

***Controller***

```
var clientes = (select u in model.clientes ......).ToList();

ViewBag.Clientes = new SelectList(clientes, "ClienteID", "Nome");
ViewBag.Telefones = new SelectList(clientes, "telefone", "telefone");
```

***View***

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Clientes) /* Gera um select com nomes e value o ClienteID */

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteFone, (SelectList)ViewBag.Telefones) /* Gera um select com telefones e value o telefone */
```

Espero que tenha entendido o uso, a validação continua a mesma coisa, os campos e a lista no controller você altera para a lista de clientes do seu sistema.

Agora para popular o segundo `DropDownList` selecionando com base no primeiro, será necessário o uso de `javascript`

***View***

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Clientes, new {id="clienteID"}) /* Gera um select com nomes e value o ClienteID */

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteFone, String.Empty, new {id="clienteFone"})
```

***Controller***

```
public JsonResult ListaTelefones(int clienteID) {
   var telefones = (from u in model.telefones where u.ClienteID select u.telefone).toList(); //Nesse caso estou usando uma tabela ficticia com os telefones do cliente cadastrado

   return Json(telefones, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

***Jquery***

```
$('#clienteID').change(function() {
   var clienteID = $(this).val();

   $.get('/MeuController/ListaTelefones', {clienteID : clienteID}).done(function(data){
      var drop = $('#clienteFones');
      drop.html("");
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         drop.append('<option val="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>');
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: estou tendo problemas ao colocar os id's nos dropDowns, é dessa forma mesmo?

Comment: Que tipo de problema?

Comment: não estou recebendo o valor da segunda dropdown para cadastrar no banco, quando seleciono o cliente visualizo os telefones mas não esta sendo executado pelo metodo Create na minha controller

Comment: Isso ocorre por causa do "bind" que o MVC faz com os dados, esqueça a criação com razor e faça `<select id="clienteFone" name="clienteFone"></select>` Provavelmente agora deve passar.